# Angular variable not updating, attempting to call $apply results in "digest already in progress" error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a bunch of properties on an object that are determined dynamically:

```
$scope.buttons.isVisible = {
                buttonOne:      $scope.timeBetween > -(60 * 60) && $scope.timeBetween < 30,
                buttonTwo:      $scope.timeBetween > -(60 * 15) && $scope.timeBetween < -(60 * 8),
                buttonThree:    $scope.timeBetween > -(60 * 15)
}
```

I use these variables to determine the visibility of some buttons on a page:

```
<button class="canned-response" ng-if="buttons.isVisible.buttonOne">Button Text</button>
```

The variable `$scope.timeBetween` is updated once per second inside of a function which is a callback of a countdown directive:

```
$scope.setTimeBetween = function(relativeSecondsBetween) {
    $scope.timeBetween = relativeSecondsBetween;
};
```

An example of the usage of the directive:

```
<countdown countdown-to="someVar" callback="setTimeBetween"></countdown>
```

**The issue is that changes to `$scope.timeBetween` are being made, but those changes are not propagating through to my button visibility booleans.**

If I try and call `$scope.$apply()` at the end of the `setTimeBetween` function, I get a "digest already in progress" error. Wrapping the variable assignment in a `$timeout` does nothing either.

What's the best solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button visibility booleans are evaluated only once.

One solution is to define them as functions:

```
buttonOne: function () {
    return $scope.timeBetween...;
}
```

And then call the functions in ng-if:

```
ng-if="buttons.isVisible.buttonOne()"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to watch $scope.timeBetween for changes, then update your button visibility object.

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $scope.timeBetween;
}, function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.buttons.isVisible = {
        buttonOne: newValue > -(60 * 60) && newValue < 30,
        buttonTwo: newValue > -(60 * 15) && newValue < -(60 * 8),
        buttonThree: newValue > -(60 * 15)
    };
});
```

Also, as a best practice, you should set up this watch in your directive's link function, not the controller.